# Gitlab migration from 6.2.3 to 7.8.1

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

We are using GitLab 6.2.3 and I'm currently migrating all our servers to 7.8.1.
We had moved gitlab db to mysql server during 6.2.3 installation.

Since these servers don't talk to outside world, I did fresh 7.8.1 installation in different area and pointed to the earlier database.

GitLab is not starting now. To diagnose I did

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

, and found:

```
hooks directories in repos are links: ... rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 
  'bitnami_gitlab.projects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `projects`
```

What could be the issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All migration scenarios described in [doc/updates](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/doc/update) involve a database upgrade step:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Make sure you have done that step, or the database wouldn't be compliant with a 7.x GitLab server.

The [OP maestromani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799444/maestromani) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769765/gitlab-migration-from-6-2-3-to-7-8-1/29769849#comment47686013_29769849):

> `/home/git` got link to old gitlabshell path. Linking to new one worked.

Comment: Running into following error now...== 20140903115954 MigrateToNewShell: migrating ================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Failed to rewrite gitlab-shell hooks in repositories/opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/db/migrate/20140903115954_migrate_to_new_shell.rb:7:in `change'
/opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/opt/gitlab/apps/gitlab/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activereco

Comment: trace didn't help either. all git hooks directory got correct permission.

Comment: @maestromani what did you do to make that migration command work?

Comment: /home/git got link to old gitlabshell path. linking to new one worked... Thank you for your help.

Comment: @maestromani Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.